# Vim tabular alignment first column different

Tags: vim, latex, tabular

I’m trying to format tables in LaTeX nicely using the Tabular command, and frequently I’ll want to right-align the leftmost column, then left align everything else. Using `:'<,'>Tabularize /&/r1c1l0` *almost* works, but only on the first column pair; the rest of the table is weirdly aligned almost as if Tabular is repeating that sequence.

How can I write a command that will align the table code without me having to type something like `:'<,'>Tabularize /&/r1c1l0c1l0c1l0…`?

EDIT: Example table code

```
\begin{longtable}{>{\bfseries}l >{\scshape}Fl -l -l -l -l -l -l -l -l -l -l}
    \toprule
    Case & & \SetRowStyle{\scshape} nil     & 1sg      & 2sg      & 3sg       & 1du;inc  & 2du      & 1pl;inc  & 1pl;exc  & 2pl      & 3pl \\
    \midrule\endhead
\multirow{4}{*}{Focal}          & nat & -a      & -ai      & -uta     & -ima      & -iva     & -etua    & -isa     & -ečé     & -atá     & -amia \\
                                & sgv & -ena    & -enai    & -enta    & -enima    & -eniva   & -entua   & -enisa   & -enčé    & -entá    & -emia \\
                                & du  & -eva    & -evai    & -evta    & -evima    & -eviva   & -evtua   & -evisa   & -evčé    & -evtá    & -evmia \\
                                & pl  & -esa    & -esai    & -esta    & -esima    & -esiva   & -estua   & -esisa   & -esčé    & -está    & -esmia \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{Nominative}     & nat & -am     & -aim     & -utam    & -imam     & -ium     & -etum    & -isam    & -ečem    & -atám    & -amim \\
                                & sgv & -enam   & -enaim   & -entam   & -enimam   & -enium   & -entum   & -ensim   & -enčem   & -entám   & -emim \\
                                & du  & -evam   & -evaim   & -evtam   & -evimam   & -evium   & -evtum   & -evsim   & -evčem   & -evtám   & -evmim \\
                                & pl  & -esam   & -esaim   & -estam   & -esimam   & -esium   & -estum   & -essim   & -esčem   & -estám   & -esmim \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{Absolutive}     & nat & -aš     & -aiš     & -utaš    & -imaš     & -iuš     & -etuš    & -isaš    & -ečeš    & -atáš    & -amiš \\
                                & sgv & -enaš   & -enaiš   & -entaš   & -enimaš   & -eniuš   & -entuš   & -ensiš   & -enčeš   & -entáš   & -emiš \\
                                & du  & -evaš   & -evaiš   & -evtaš   & -evimaš   & -eviuš   & -evtuš   & -evsiš   & -evčeš   & -evtáš   & -evmiš \\
                                & pl  & -esaš   & -esaiš   & -estaš   & -esimaš   & -esiuš   & -estuš   & -essiš   & -esčeš   & -estáš   & -esmiš \\
\bottomrule
  \caption{Consonant-final animate noun suffixes\label{tab:nst_animate_consonant_stem_suffixes}}
\end{longtable}
```

It compiles just fine but I’d like the source code to be formatted somewhat nicer.

Comment: Can you perhaps add an example table to the question? Otherwise it is hard (for me at least) to tell what the command is doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may find [vim-easy-align](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) useful.

Try

```
:'<,'>EasyAlign&mrl*
```

which is a shorthand notation for

```
:'<,'>EasyAlign & { 'mode_sequence': 'rl*' }
```

- `&` tells the plugin to align text using predefined `&` rule for LaTeX tables
- `rl*` means `right, left, left, left, ...`

You can adjust left and right margin around the delimiter as follows:

```
:'<,'>EasyAlign&mrl*l0r1
```

a shorthand notation for

```
:'<,'>EasyAlign & { 'mode_sequence': 'rl*', 'left_margin': 0, 'right_margin': 1 }
```